# Changing airlines in Bangkok, Thailand in transit from Laos to Colombo, Sri Lanka

Tags: customs-and-immigration, short-connections, eu-citizens, bkk

I will be traveling from Laos with Lao Airlines, transiting in Bangkok to Colombo with SriLankan Airlines, the upcoming end of September. My flight with Lao Airlines will arrive in Bangkok at 19:40, and my SriLankan Airlines flight leaves Bangkok at 21:50. I will be 2:10 hours in transit.

Will this be enough time for the transit?

Do I still have to pass Immigration & Customs at  Bangkok to check in my bags for my other flight, given that it's two different airlines?

I have a European passport.

Comment: Did you buy a single ticket, or separate tickets?

Comment: I did not buy it yet @MichaelHampton . It's 2 separate single tickets. On skyscanner.com you can buy those 2 separate tickets as 1 purchased  ticket.

Comment: That's a single ticket covering two flights then.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a single ticket (and based on your description it sounds like one), **you'll be fine**.

Your bags will be checked through to Colombo, and you do not need to pass through immigration or customs. You *may* need to visit a transfer desk to pick up your second boarding pass if this cannot be issued in Laos.

Bangkok Suvarnabhumi is a large airport, but it's also all in a single enormous building and even walking the whole length of several kilometers only takes half an hour max, with a little help form the moving walkways.  So two hours should be plenty, and even gives you a little buffer if your flight is delayed.  Also, since you have a single ticket, you'll be put on the next available flight for free even if you do miss it due to a delay.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @jpatokal . It is really helpful.


One more question...In case I buy my Lao Airlines ticket (Vientianne-Bangkok) separate and Sri Lankan Airlines ticket (Bangkok-Colombo) separate, will this still be seen as a transit in Bangkok OR do I have to follow all the immigration and customs procedures and check in again in Bangkok? (Buying this tickets separately is cheaper then buying them as 1 together).

Comment: If you buy them separately, you will most likely not be able to check bags through without collecting them and checking in again.